# Python Permutation Program Flow help

Tags: python, workflow, recursion

i found this code at activestate, it takes a string and prints permutations of the string.
I understand that its a recursive function but i dont really understand how it works, it'd be great if someone could walk me through the program flow, thanks a bunch!

```
import sys

def printList(alist, blist=[]):
    if not len(alist): print ''.join(blist)
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        blist.append(alist.pop(i))
        printList(alist, blist)
        alist.insert(i, blist.pop())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = 'love'
    if len(sys.argv) > 1: k = sys.argv[1]
    printList(list(k))
```

Comment: That's horrible code imo. Good there's always `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: I got it from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66463-permutation/.
Its messy but i want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can figure out how `printList` behaves by drawing a recursion tree. Each node consists of two elements: an `alist` and a `blist`. The root has the `alist` with the initial sequence of items you want to permute, and an empty `blist`.
Each node of the tree has one branch for each element of that node's `alist`; you move from a 'father' node to each one of its 'children' by choosing an element from the father's `alist` and:

- assigning to the child's `alist` the father's `alist` *minus that element*;
- assigning to the child's `blist` the father's `blist` plus that element *appended to its end*.

The leafs have an empty `alist`, and since following different paths from the root to the leafs you have to choose elements from the root's `alist` in different orders, the `blist` of the leafs themselves contain all the various permutations of the root's `alist`.

For example (`[abc],[] == alist,blist`):

```
                           [abc],[] 
                         /     |     \
                       a/     b|      \c
                       /       |       \
                  [bc],[a]  [ac],[b]   [ab],[c]
                  /     \
                b/       \c
                /         \
           [c],[ab]      [b],[ac]
              |             |
             c|             |b
              |             |
           [],[abc]      [],[acb]


def printList(alist, blist=[]):
    # if alist is empty, we are in a 'leaf' in the recursion tree;
    # then blist contains one permutation; print it
    if not len(alist): print ''.join(blist)

    # ELSE, for each possible position in alist,
    for i in range(len(alist)):

        # move the element at that position from alist to the end of blist
        blist.append(alist.pop(i))

        # go to the 'children' node and do the printing job for its subtree
        printList(alist, blist)

        # then move back the element from the end of blist to its original
        # position in alist, so we can continue with the for loop
        # without altering alist
        alist.insert(i, blist.pop())
```

Comment: +1 for the ascii tree (and the good explanation of course ;-)

Comment: Its pretty clear when u put it like that, thanks for helping a newbie out! Vote up when i hit 15!

Answer (score 3):

To understand it clearly remove the loop with alist=love and blist initialized to []:
The 4 printlist calls in the for loop will now be(at first level of recursion):

```
   printList("ove","l");
   printList("lve","o");
   printList("loe","v");
   printList("lov","e");
```

Each of these printList calls has bList initialized to all possible permutations of one lettered lists, and alist has the remaining 3 letters. This is will continue until alist becomes empty and all the letters are in blist (and the printing happens `if not len(alist): print ''.join(blist)`)

In the second level of recursion for example

```
   printList("ove","l") will result in 3 calls

   printList("ve","lo");
   printList("oe","lv");
   printList("ov","le");
```

Total permutations = 4(firstlevel) * 3(2nd level) * 2 * 1

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug - Here is an elementary permutation code in python along with explanation from my blog.
[Playing with recursion - string permutation](http://devconvert.blogspot.com/2009/09/playing-with-recursion-string.html)